# Can you get the value being switched on inside a switch expression

Tags: c#

Is there a way to do this

```cs
int i = object.GetString() switch
{
    "this" => 1,
    "that" => 2,
    "the other" => 3,
    _ => someMethod([switch value])
}
```

to use the value being switched on inside the switch expression?
Or do I have to do this

```cs
var myString = object.GetString()
int i = myString switch
{
    "this" => 1,
    "that" => 2,
    "the other" => 3,
    _ => someMethod(myString)
}
```

I know it's not that big of a deal to declare `myString`; I'm just wondering if the syntax exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about this?

```
int i = object.GetString() switch
{
    "this" => 1,
    "that" => 2,
    "the other" => 3,
    { } s => someMethod(s)
}
```

It will get anything but `null`.

Of course it is only usable if you want to catch any type there. If you know for sure it will be a `string` value, and someMethod expects a `string` value also, you can go like this:

```
string s => someMethod(s)
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, it's easy:

```
int i = object.GetString() switch
{
    "this" => 1,
    "that" => 2,
    "the other" => 3,
    string value => someMethod(value)
};
```