# Can you refer to case values inside the code block of the switch statement?

Tags: java

So can you do something like this in Java:

[Can you get the value being switched on inside a switch expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66147790/can-you-get-the-value-being-switched-on-inside-a-switch-expression)

I have quite a few cases in my code which look like this (actual logic code removed for clarity reasons):

```
    switch (weatherSystem.getRealClass().getSimpleName())
    {
        case "SyncWeatherSystem":
            logger.info("initializing sync weather system");
            …
            break;
        case "AsyncWeatherSystem":
            logger.info("initializing  async weather system");
            …       
            break;
        case "FixedWeatherSystem":
            logger.info("initializing fixed weather system");
            …
            break;
        case "NoWeatherSystem":
            logger.info("initializing no weather system");
            …
            break;
    }
```

And I really would love to do like:

```
    switch (weatherSystem.getRealClass().getSimpleName())
    {
        case "SyncWeatherSystem":
            logger.info("initializing {}", case.value);
            …
            break;
        case "AsyncWeatherSystem":
            logger.info("initializing {}", case.value); 
            …
            break;
        case "FixedWeatherSystem":
            logger.info("initializing {}", case.value);
            …
            break;
        case "NoWeatherSystem":
            logger.info("initializing {}", case.value);
            …
            break;
    }
```

Is this possible in Java?

Comment: You don't need the `switch` at all - just use string concatenation "directly."

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine Only if `default` isn't a **no-op**.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch True.

Comment: Why do you need an alternative way to get the value, instead of using the same expression as in the `switch` parentheses? If it takes time to generate and return the value, store it in a variable (perhaps a `final` one) before using it in a `switch`.

Answer (score 4):

No. It is not. But, `weatherSystem.getRealClass().getSimpleName()` is. I suggest you save that value to a local variable. And all your `case`(s) seem to do the same thing. So, as posted, you could simplify it. Like

```
String sName = weatherSystem.getRealClass().getSimpleName();
switch (sName)
{
    case "SyncWeatherSystem":
    case "AsyncWeatherSystem":
    case "FixedWeatherSystem":
    case "NoWeatherSystem":
        logger.info("initializing {}", sName);
        break;
}
```

Comment: Good Answer. I suggest being more explicit about the main change being the move of the  call to `getSimpleName` to a named local variable. I had to look a few times to see what you did. Perhaps you should just show that first, before separately showing the collapsed `case` cascade.

Comment: I am sorry - the actual logic code is actually removed, there is code between logger.info and break;

Comment: @Snorik In the future, I suggest you show additional but irrelevant code by adding a line with a single character, ellipsis `…`.

Comment: @BasilBourque thank you for the reminder. Just added [...] to make it clear

Comment: @Snorik I altered your edit to use the actual [ellipsis character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsis) ( Option + Semicolon on macOS), and to move indented with your code.